# **closed** How to create magento admin custom page with custom table Like Sales->Orders

Tags: php, mysql, magento, admin, custom-pages

**CLosed I can do it I mix code from 2 answer to make my page**

I want to make  special order page with My custom database table

Can I create New magento admin Page layout like this

[I want layout like this page](http://openerp-magento-connector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_images/Sales_orders.png)

I want to show

> Orders  OrdersDate  CustomerID  CustomerCompany  SKU ProductName Qty,
>   Total Status  Action

and mydatabase table name is specialorder
in Fields in table have

```
order_no PK (from product id)
order_item_number PK (to show in Orders)
creat_date (to show in OrdersDate)
Cusid (to show in CustomerID)
Cusname (to show in CustomerCompany)
sku (to show in SKU)
Productname (to show in ProductName )
price 
qty (to show in Qty,)
total_price (to show in Total)
status (to show in Status)
```

data in table like this (order_no + order_item_no = pk)

> 1 1 date cusid cusname sku P.name price qty total status
>
> 2 1 date cusid cusname sku P.name price qty total status
>
> 2 2 date cusid cusname sku P.name price qty total status

How can I use this table to show in my custom admin page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the following steps to create module in admin panel with your custom table.

Create module in your local directory (app/code/local/Pfay/Test), Where test -> .
Inside this structure create all these directories Helper,etc,Block,Model,Controllers

Lets start with etc create config.xml file in side this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
    <modules>
        <Pfay_Test>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Pfay_Test>
    </modules>
    <global>
            <blocks>
                <test>
                     <class>Pfay_Test_Block</class>
                </test>
            </blocks>
            <models>
                <test>
                     <class>Pfay_Test_Model</class>
                     <resourceModel>test_mysql4</resourceModel>
                 </test>
                <test_mysql4>
                     <class>Pfay_Test_Model_Mysql4</class>
                     <entities>
                         <test>
                           <table>pfay_test</table>
                         </test>
                      </entities>
                </test_mysql4>
            </models>
                <!-- allow the plugin to read and write -->
            <resources>
                    <!-- connection to write -->
                    <test_write>
                        <connection>
                            <use>core_write</use>
                        </connection>
                    </test_write>
                    <!-- connection to read -->
                   <test_read>
                      <connection>
                         <use>core_read</use>
                      </connection>
                   </test_read>
            </resources>
             <!-- -/- -->
    </global>
     <frontend>
       <routers>
          <routeurfrontend>
              <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                 <module>Pfay_Test</module>
                 <frontName>test</frontName>
              </args>
          </routeurfrontend>
       </routers>
       <layout>
           <updates>
                <test>
                     <file>test.xml</file>
                </test>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
        <admin>
         <routers>
             <test>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                   <module>Pfay_Test</module>
                   <frontName>admintest</frontName>
                </args>
             </test>
          </routers>
     </admin>
     <adminhtml>
       <layout>
          <updates>
              <test>
                  <file>test.xml</file>
               </test>
          </updates>
       </layout>
       <menu>
          <test translate="title" module="adminhtml">
             <title>Import XLS</title>
             <sort_order>100</sort_order>
             <children>
                 <set_time>
                       <title>Add product through XLS</title>
                       <action>admintest/adminhtml_index</action>
                  </set_time>
              </children>
           </test>
        </menu>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

My table name is **Pfay_test** add your table name instead of this.

Now in controllers create directory **Adminhtml** inside this create create your controller **IndexController.php**

```
<?php
class Pfay_Test_Adminhtml_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    protected function _initAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout()->_setActiveMenu('test/set_time')
                ->_addBreadcrumb('test Manager','test Manager');
       return $this;
     }
      public function indexAction()
      {
         $this->_initAction();
         $this->renderLayout();
      }
```

}

where **set_time** is you menu name added in config.xml file.

Now move to you block section where you will create you Grid.
Inside Block directory create `Adminhtml > Grid.php`

```
class Pfay_Test_Block_Adminhtml_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
     //where is the controller
     $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_test';
     $this->_blockGroup = 'test';
     //text in the admin header
     $this->_headerText = 'XLS file management';
     //value of the add button

     parent::__construct();
     }
}
```

Next create a directory Test > Grid.php

```
<?php
class Pfay_Test_Block_Adminhtml_Test_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
   public function __construct()
   {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->setId('contactGrid');
       $this->setDefaultSort('id_pfay_test');
       $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
       $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
   }
   protected function _prepareCollection()
   {
      $collection = Mage::getModel('test/test')->getCollection();
      $this->setCollection($collection);
      return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
   protected function _prepareColumns()
   {
       $this->addColumn('id_pfay_test',
             array(
                    'header' => 'ID',
                    'align' =>'right',
                    'width' => '50px',
                    'index' => 'id_pfay_test',
               ));
       $this->addColumn('nom',
               array(
                    'header' => 'nom',
                    'align' =>'left',
                    'index' => 'nom',
              ));
       $this->addColumn('prenom', array(
                    'header' => 'prenom',
                    'align' =>'left',
                    'index' => 'prenom',
             ));
        $this->addColumn('telephone', array(
                     'header' => 'telephone',
                     'align' =>'left',
                     'index' => 'telephone',
          ));
         return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
         return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $row->getId()));
    }
}
```

Now move to your Model Inside Model create **Test.php** and **Mysql4**

In Test.php :

```
<?php
class Pfay_Test_Model_Test extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
     public function _construct()
     {
         parent::_construct();
         $this->_init('test/test');
     }
}
```

Here (test/test) is  `Pfay_<modulename>_Model_<modulename> -> (<modulename>/<modulename>)`

Now inside `Pfay > Test > Model > Mysql4` folder create Test.php and Test

In Test.php :

```
<?php
class Pfay_Test_Model_Mysql4_Test extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
     public function _construct()
     {
         $this->_init('test/test', 'id_pfay_test');
     }
}
```

Where **id_pfay_test** is unique key of your table.

```
Pfay >Test >Model >Mysql4 >Test > create a file Collection.php

<?php
class Pfay_Test_Model_Mysql4_Test_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
 {
     public function _construct()
     {
         parent::_construct();
         $this->_init('test/test');
     }
}
```

Final step inform magento about your module : create file Pfay_Test.xml in

**/app/etc/modules**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Pfay_Test>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Pfay_Test>
   </modules>

</config>
```

**Note :** Change Module name and package name according to you.

Feel free if you have any query regarding this.

Comment: Thank you for your help

if my table name is not like package_module can i do right that?

Comment: yes, add your table name in config.xml file like i have added <table>pfay_test</table> (replace you table name with pfay_test)

Comment: I change and check every package module and any table but in my custom page is blank

but admin page still have menu header and footer  but other is gone

or i mistake in 'code->local->Special->Order->Block->Adminhtml->Grid.php




class Special_Order_Block_Adminhtml_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
     $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_order';
     $this->_blockGroup = 'order';
     $this->_headerText = 'Manage Special Order';
     parent::__construct();
     }
}

Comment: My file and folder in code -> local -> Special -> order -> is
[Block [Adminhtml [Order -> Grid.php] Grid.php] ]
[Controllers [ Adminhtml -> IndexController.php]]
[Helper]
[Model  [ Mysql4 [Order -> Collection.php] Order.php] Order.php]
[etc -> Config.xml]

Comment: Did you change packagename and modulename in config.xml file

Comment: Yes i change every packagename and all Module/modulename to my name

**PS**

i change menu to report sale 

**PS2** i try to delete code in all Grid.php but don't have any change after delete that code?

Comment: Please check for your collection in your sandbox file.

Comment: i don't know what about sandbox file.?

Comment: Create a sandbox.php file on your root directory and add the below code (Change (test/test) according to your module):

<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();
 $collection = Mage::getModel('test/test')->getCollection();
print_r($collection);
?>

Comment: not any thing change this page is look like blank admin page?

Comment: you are doing something wrong...please cross check your code..if you will face same problem then upload your module on github, I will check and resolve your issue

Comment: i try to make new one again is same problem?

i thing because 
 [Block [Adminhtml [Order -> Grid.php] Grid.php] ] 
in Folder Block root not have any php file ?

Comment: code -> local -> Special -> order ->  
[Block [Adminhtml -> Grid.php [Order -> Grid.php] ] ] 
[Controllers [ Adminhtml -> IndexController.php]] 
[Helper] 
[Model -> Order.php [ Mysql4 -> Order.php [Order -> Collection.php] ] ] 
[etc -> Config.xml]

Comment: i try to do like [link](http://www.summasolutions.net/blogposts/custom-reports-magento)

is show layout but data is not show and i con't like that template and period

Comment: i try to check and rewrite again  I thing we miss test.xml

in config.xml write to this file 2 time in layout part but don't have this file for write?

Comment: i try to not edit and create like you but it same problem 
i upload pic for you
[link](http://imageshack.com/a/img674/1005/jQVB6w.jpg)

Comment: Can you tell me how to fix that I try to do but result it same

Answer (score 0):

Try using the built in Magento Grid. As to not duplicate content, try this:

- http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/

Comment: I  try to do like this but in prepareCollection 
i don't have idea to get data from my table

i try to do but data is not show anyway

can you tech me about this point

Comment: I come back and help tomorrow, off for the night.

Comment: Thank you for your help i will try to do waiting for you